# Testing a Django driven web app

Tags: django, system-testing, web-client

I have a web app that opens and closes background process on the server. I want to simulate multiple users logging in and out of the site as well as pressing all the buttons (general interaction). I am testing the app in general as well as how well the background process are juggled.

Are there specific libraries that i should look at that would simulate a web client? This is system level testing as opposed to unit testing..i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [Watir](http://watir.com/).